# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cos( \frac{x}{n^2})$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the series
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cos( \frac{x}{n^2})
$$
Then I have to show that $S$ converges uniformly. I think I have to use Weiterstrass M-test but I am not sure whether or not that
$$ 
\left| cos(\frac{x}{n^2}) \right| \leq 1
$$
is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that
$$
\left| sin(\frac{x}{n^2}) \right| \leq \frac{|x|}{n^2}
$$
but I don't think it is the same for cosine? Am I able to say that
$$
\left| \frac{1}{n^2} \cos( \frac{x}{n^2}) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
Thus as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges $S$ converges uniformly by Weiterstrass' M-test.

Comment: $|\cos \theta | \leq 1$ for any real number $\theta$.

Comment: So my approach is alright?

Comment: Yes, it is alright, because of what Kavi Rama Murthy said.